# what can be the regex expression for a single alpahbet

Tags: java, regex

What can be the regex expression where the input:

```
'A'  --- is valid
"AA" --- is invalid.
```

I tried `^[A-Z]$` which doesn't work

Comment: Maybe `^'[A-Z]'$`?

Comment: The `^[A-Z]$` expression will match a 1-length `String` with any capital letter ranging from `A` to `Z`. If it "doesn't work", there's something you are missing. Show your code.

Comment: Can you show the code where `^[A-Z]$` doesn't work

Comment: You don't need the `^` start of the string character in java.

Comment: a simple `[A-Z]` should be enough without the starts end ends with regex modifier.

Comment: it can be   ^A{1}$

Comment: think he mean `(?i)^[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$`

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to tie it to the start or end of line.
    /b[A-Z]/b